# VS2017 not downloading headers from WSL

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to remote build a C++ helloworld in VisualStudio2017 on WSL Ubuntu.
I followed the instructions as outlined by Goodner on MSDN here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/11/26/using-visual-studio-for-cross-platform-c-development-targeting-windows-and-linux/

And for WSL this:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server

**Problem:**
Intellisense can't find the include headers and I cannot debug my program. The build on the Linux however is successful and can be run from the bash.

I figured the [Remote Headers IntelliSense Manager](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/intellisense-for-remote-linux-headers/) should have been able to resolve the issue, but it's not downloading the headers to my Windows header cache

Any help on how to correctly set up VS2017 remote build/debug on WSL to build C, C++ and existing Make projects is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use the actual headers from the WSL linux instance as includes for my VisualStudio project.  It is ok to READ them.. just don't EVER edit them from Windows.

Here is a crumb to get you started:
$(UserProfile)\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\usr\include

This also gives me a guarentee that the code being compiled is the same as the one being used by intellisense.

One other tip.. I don't actually use that HURKING LONG PATH..  I junction it elsewhere and use the shorter path.. This also makes it easy to switch distros without changing my project files over and over.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in VS 2022 using WSL2. This worked for me.

> Go to Project -> Click Rescan Solution.

This force downloads the Linux headers into Windows Header Cache.